# Correctly align Advanced Format drive?

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive

I bought a new WD Hard Drive. 250Gb, WD2500BPT.
I installed Ubuntu (13.04 was it?) on it. I heard that I don't have to worry about the block size/ alignment.

However,

```
    cat /sys/block/sda/queue/logical_block_size
```

shows 512, not 4096.

also fdisk tells in the startup that the disk isn't aligned correctly.

What do I have to do?
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked up that specific model; however, assuming that it *is* an Advanced Format model, you should use your partitioning software to view the *start* points of all the partitions and verify that they're all multiples of 8. (The extended partition, if you've got one, is an exception to this rule; don't worry about it's alignment, since it's irrelevant.) For instance:

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8e0cb6b5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63    20033054    10016496   27  Unknown
/dev/sda2        20033055   103699574    41833260    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3   *   103699575   249907139    73103782+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5       103699638   131781194    14040778+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6       131781258   183992444    26105593+   b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda7       183992508   187076924     1542208+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8   *   187076988   187398224      160618+  83  Linux
/dev/sda9       187398288   249907139    31254426   8e  Linux LVM
```

This example is from a non-Advanced Format disk, and it is *not* properly aligned -- `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` both begin on sectors with odd numbers, and so can't be divisible by 8. (`/dev/sda3` also begins on an odd-numbered sector, but as it's an extended partition, this fact is irrelevant for this partition.) I haven't bothered to check the others, but a few seconds with a calculator would reveal their status. Since this disk isn't an Advanced Format model, this isn't a problem; but if it were such a disk, performance could be significantly degraded.

If you find that your disk is improperly aligned, you may be able to move/resize the offending partition(s), or it may be easier to start over again, since it sounds like you've just installed Ubuntu. Generally speaking, recent versions of Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions) set things up correctly by default, so if your partitions aren't properly aligned, you may want to consider why that's the case. For instance, if you set up your partitions with an old version of `fdisk`, it wouldn't use the new alignment rules and so might produce something like I've shown above. If that's the case, use a newer tool or learn to set up the partitions with proper alignment using the old tool.

Comment: Thanks.
Seems like I've got a small extended partition, which isn't "properly aligned". All other partitions are fine.
I don't know what it is there for.
You said that extended partitions don't matter, so is my HD fine and as fast as it can be, even if the one extended partition isn't "aligned properly"?

Comment: Extended partitions hold logical partitions. The alignment of the logical partitions contained within the extended partition is important, but the alignment of the extended partition itself is irrelevant.